# Accessing Router deployed at remote location using VPN

Tags: router, vpn, remote-access, tunnel, openwrt

I am new to Networking and need help with some problems.

I have Setup a router with `OPEN-WRT` and/or `DDWRT` which have VPN clients inside them. I studied many VPN concepts and came to know about `site to site VPN`. Using this can I access the router from same VPn network?

I want to access this router from Home PC which is at Remote location . by access I mean the Dashboard of the Router which we get when we type `192.168.1.1` while in the same network.

Is it possible using `OpenVPN` in which I will have one VPN server and Router having VPN client will be in the same VPN network.

Also this router should be connected to Internet not only the VPN network like `Split Tunneling`

Answer (score 1):

In line of principle, a router's GUI can be accessed from `both` the WAN side `and` the LAN side. This is however dangerous, because it exposes your router from WAN-side attacks of real hackers. So, you should **first thing** check that your router is **not** accessible from the WAN side; if it is, you should disable that option. How to do that depends upon whether you have DD-WRT or OpenWRT; Googling it returns many good hits.

Once you have done this, you will be able to access the router's GUI if and only if you have an IP address within the LAN administered by the router, *i.e.* you are on the LAN side.

From a remote connection you can achieve that through OpenVPN if you have enabled it in the *bridge* mode, which assigns to the client (you on the remote station) an IP address belonging to the LAN net administered by the router. The same result cannot be achieved (at least, not easily) withe the OpenVPN in a tunnel mode (the alternative to the bridge mode).

Lastly, you can connect either your single pc to the remote server, or the whole subnet on which you are. This last configuration is called `site-to-site` OpenVPN, because you are basically taking two separate, distant LANs and are joining them seamlessly into one. To answer your first question, if this `site-to-site` OpenVPN is in the *bridge* mode, then you will be able to access the GUI of your router from *any* pc in your subnet.

If this is however too much, you may choose to connect to the OpenVPN only your pc. In this case, you will not have a `site-to-site` OpenVPN, but just one client (your pc). Once again, make sure that you have a bridge mode OpenVPN, and you are ok.

The choice between `site-to-site` and `single-client` is a matter for you to decide: do you want to give access to the other LAN to all LAN clients (this means, all pcs of LAN1 can reach all pcs of LAN2 **and viceversa**)? If so, `site-to-site` is for you. Otherwise, just go `single-client`.

Comment: I used SSH tunneling instead